The Correctness of This Phrase
Does this phrase sound idiomatic:

Hoping the quotes will delight you as much as I was...

Or is there a better way of wording it?

I'd phrase it differently, maybe something like: "Hoping the quotes will delight you as much as they did me." I'm not sure if "was" is grammatically wrong, but it sounds a bit weird. It's lacking in parallelism.

"As much as I was what?" If you mean delighted, as Stuart says, it lacks parallelism.

Another way to reword is it

Hoping you will be delighted by the quotes as much as I was.

The point in all these rewrites is that the two clauses should have parallel structure. In your version the first clause is active ("quotes will delight you"), while the second is passive ("I was [delighted by the quotes]").
It's not ungrammatical if you include the elided text, but that makes it wordy and unnatural. And when you leave out the elided text, the audience will assume parallel structure, so they'll expect "I was" to be an active statement, and this creates the question of what you were.

That doesn't really work grammatically, though it is the kind of thing someone could say if they don't really pay attention to how they structured the sentence.
Stuart F's suggestion is grammatically perfect but kind of formal and may be a little confusing to the listener.
"Hoping the quotes will delight you as much as me" is an option, though someone might point out that there are two possible interpretations ("the quotes delighted me and I hope you feel the same", or "I delighted you and I hope the quotes delight you too").
Probably the best way to phrase it is, "Hoping the quotes will delight you as much as they delighted me."

What's wrong with "as much as they did me"? It avoids the repetition of delighted.

@KateBunting If the listener isn't perfectly fluent, it will make them pause and need to take it apart (almost draw a diagram of the sentence) to get what it meant. Other than that, it might be a style mismatch if the surrounding text isn't that formal. What's wrong with repeating a key word?

I agree that "as they did me" sounds a bit off for a casual note, even if it does avoid repeating a word. How about "Hoping you will find the quotes as delightful as I did"?
